# Where to set INSERT... SELECT in a FOR bucle for with billing system Python and MySQL

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, mariadb

I'm trying to insert multiple records in a MySQL table named 'factura' (invoice in English) using 'INSERT...SELECT' in Python.

```
#QUERY OF THE CONSULTA DEL VADOR DEL IVA JURIDICO
cursor.execute("SELECT ivajuridico FROM configuracion;")
dato1 = cursor.fetchall()
#CONSULTA DE LA INFORMACION DE LOS ARRENDATARIOS
cursor.execute("SELECT c_cod, now(), relacionip.i_cod, i_vlrenta, a_tpersona FROM contratos INNER JOIN relacionip ON contratos.r_id = relacionip.r_id INNER JOIN inmuebles ON relacionip.i_cod = inmuebles.i_cod INNER JOIN arrendatarios ON contratos.a_cc = arrendatarios.a_cc;")
dato2 = cursor.fetchall()
connect.commit()
for a in dato1:
    ivaj = a[0] #16.0 (float)
    print ivaj
    for i in dato2:
        if i[4] == 2:
            #showinfo("","Es Jurídico")
            iva = i[3]*ivaj/100 #vl arriendo*iva/100
            total = i[3]+iva
        else:
            #showinfo("","Es Natural")
            iva = 0
            total = i[3]+iva
    try:
        cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO factura_arre(c_cod, fa_fecha, fa_iva, fa_total) SELECT c_cod, now(), '%f', '%f' FROM contratos INNER JOIN relacionip ON contratos.r_id = relacionip.r_id INNER JOIN inmuebles ON relacionip.i_cod = inmuebles.i_cod INNER JOIN arrendatarios ON contratos.a_cc = arrendatarios.a_cc;''' % (iva, total))
        connect.commit()
    except:
        pass
  showinfo('Operación', "Grabado!")
```

The first query searches the value of a tax called 'IVA Jurídico' in a table named 'configuracion', which contains only one float value (16.0) and this one is applied to those legal tenant.

```
MariaDB> SELECT ivajuridico FROM configuracion;
+-------------+
| ivajuridico |
+-------------+
|          16 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then, second query searches the requiered information of the tenants and properties in some related tables The results are 8 records, because those are the total of the tenants in the database. One of them, the first one, is type legal.

```
MariaDB> SELECT c_cod, now(), relacionip.i_cod, i_vlrenta, a_tpersona FROM contratos INNER JOIN relacionip ON contratos.r_id = relacionip.r_id INNER JOIN inmuebles ON relacionip.i_cod = inmuebles.i_cod INNER JOIN arrendatarios ON contratos.a_cc = arrendatarios.a_cc;
+-------+---------------------+-------+-----------+------------+
| c_cod | now()               | i_cod | i_vlrenta | a_tpersona |
+-------+---------------------+-------+-----------+------------+
|  1509 | 2017-07-03 23:55:08 |  1140 |   5284240 |          2 |
|  1526 | 2017-07-03 23:55:08 |   170 |    687500 |          1 |
|  1528 | 2017-07-03 23:55:08 |    88 |    432000 |          1 |
| 22736 | 2017-07-03 23:55:08 |   386 |   1338000 |          1 |
| 22754 | 2017-07-03 23:55:08 |   192 |    720000 |          1 |
| 22789 | 2017-07-03 23:55:08 |  1144 |    645000 |          1 |
| 22898 | 2017-07-03 23:55:08 |   448 |   3700000 |          1 |
| 22900 | 2017-07-03 23:55:08 |   449 |   1100000 |          1 |
+-------+---------------------+-------+-----------+------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Next code, I think, it's understandable, because it defines that if a tenant is type legal, then the value of the tax for legal people must be applied, otherwise 0.

However, the rest of the code, where `try:` is and INSERT...SELECT must be executed, I got problems, because it gives me 8 records with the same rent value for all the tenants and tax 0, ignoring that one of them is legal. But, if I set `try` and its content below `else` I got 64 recodrs instead of 8.

```
mysql> select * from factura_Arre;
+--------+-------+---------------------+--------+----------+-----------+----------+
| fa_num | c_cod | fa_fecha            | fa_iva | fa_total | fa_estado | fa_notas |
+--------+-------+---------------------+--------+----------+-----------+----------+
|     40 |  1509 | 2017-06-08 01:16:01 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL     |
|     41 |  1526 | 2017-06-08 01:16:01 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL     |
|     42 |  1528 | 2017-06-08 01:16:01 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL     |
|     43 | 22736 | 2017-06-08 01:16:01 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL     |
|     44 | 22754 | 2017-06-08 01:16:01 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL     |
|     45 | 22789 | 2017-06-08 01:16:01 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL     |
|     46 | 22898 | 2017-06-08 01:16:01 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL     |
|     47 | 22900 | 2017-06-08 01:16:01 |      0 |  1100000 |         0 | NULL     |
+--------+-------+---------------------+--------+----------+-----------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The thing is where `try:` should be located or what code else do I need make it work?

Comment: Run the select statement from insert .. select by itself without the %f columns.  You'll get 8 records.  You're inserting those eight records with the last values of iva, total.  Put print statements on iva and total in the if block, else block, and just before the insert ... select and you'll see why you're getting this behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I indented the try block and removed the select from the insert.  It repeated the dato2 select being iterated.  I used c_cod from dat02 for the insert.

```
#QUERY OF THE CONSULTA DEL VADOR DEL IVA JURIDICO
cursor.execute("SELECT ivajuridico FROM configuracion;")
dato1 = cursor.fetchall()
#CONSULTA DE LA INFORMACION DE LOS ARRENDATARIOS
cursor.execute("SELECT c_cod, now(), relacionip.i_cod, i_vlrenta, a_tpersona     FROM contratos INNER JOIN relacionip ON contratos.r_id = relacionip.r_id INNER JOIN inmuebles ON relacionip.i_cod = inmuebles.i_cod INNER     JOIN arrendatarios ON contratos.a_cc = arrendatarios.a_cc;")
dato2 = cursor.fetchall()
connect.commit()
for a in dato1:
    ivaj = a[0] #16.0 (float)
    print ivaj
    for i in dato2:
        if i[4] == 2:
           #showinfo("","Es Jurídico")
           iva = i[3]*ivaj/100 #vl arriendo*iva/100
           total = i[3]+iva
       else:
           #showinfo("","Es Natural")
           iva = 0
           total = i[3]+iva
       try:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO factura_arre(c_cod, fa_fecha, fa_iva, fa_total) values ('%s', now(), '%f', '%f')" % (i[0], iva, total)) # i[0] is c_cod for the row just calculated.
         connect.commit()
       except:
          pass
   showinfo('Operación', "Grabado!")
```